# Java cut the sticks

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and I was trying to solve this problem on Hackerrank:
Here's the task:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks

> You are given N sticks, where the length of each stick is a positive
>   integer. A cut operation is performed on the sticks such that all of
>   them are reduced by the length of the smallest stick.
>
> Suppose we have six sticks of the following lengths:
>
> 5 4 4 2 2 8
>
> Then, in one cut operation we make a cut of length 2 from each of the six
>   sticks. For the next cut operation four sticks are left (of non-zero length), > whose lengths are the following:
>
> 3 2 2 6
>
> The above step is repeated until no sticks are left.
>
> Given the length of N sticks, print the number of sticks that are left before > each subsequent cut operations.
>
> Note: For each cut operation, you have to recalcuate the length of smallest
>   sticks (excluding zero-length sticks).

Here is my attempt at it, but it doesnt seem to be working. The output gets stuck in while loop (4 gets printed out infinitely)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    private static int findMin (int[] A)
    {
        int min = A[0];
        for (int i =0; i<A.length; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] < min)
            {
                min = A[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
    private static int countNonZeros (int[] A)
    {
        int zeros = 0;
        for (int i =0; i<A.length; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] == 0)
            {
                zeros++;
            }
        }
        int nonZeros = A.length - zeros;
        return nonZeros;
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] A = new int[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            A[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }             
        int nums = countNonZeros(A);
        while (nums > 0)
        {
            int mins = findMin(A);
            for (int j = 0; j<A.length; j++)
            {
                A[j]=A[j]-mins;
            }
            nums = countNonZeros(A);
            System.out.println(nums);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated
(PS I know I can just look the solution up somewhere, but I want to know why my code isn't working)

Comment: Did you learn how to use a debugger? If not, what IDE are you using? Instead of someone telling you what's wrong, you can find out for yourself.

Comment: it is an online test and an online compiler... Didnt know I could find this out via a debugger, will try to work on this now.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have is that your `findMin` is not excluding zero-length elements, so once you have a zero that will be the min, and as a result an iteration of the while loop will be the same as the previous iteration, having subtracted 0 from each of the elements of `A`.

Comment: oh my god... Feeling like a retard after reading this... Thank you so much for pointing it out!!!! Really appreciated!